# Moodle registration with user's personal information and admin confirmation

Tags: moodle

I'm looking for integrating user registration with the payment gateway and the admin confirmation, after the user enrolled and paid the course he chose to take part to the user is supposed to upload a picture and the passport, is there any plugin or solution which can do that all at once without having the admin to manually ask for this information?

I found this plugin after googling it up: https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_emailadmin, however it is too much of a manual approach for my project.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.